# Telethon issue: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'send_message' was never awaited

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

Help me please to solve an error in my code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events

#Ids
api_id = 99999
api_hash = 'secret_word'

client = TelegramClient('secret_chat', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=('user1')))
async def normal_handler(event):
    s_user_id=event.message.to_dict()['from_id']
    if s_user_id != 99999999:
        client.send_message('user3', 'Test')



@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=('user2')))
async def normal_handler(event):
    s_user_id=event.message.to_dict()['from_id']
    if s_user_id != 99999999:
        client.send_message('user3', 'Test')

client.start()

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

When user1 or user2 send me messages I have an error in my program:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'send_message' was never awaited
>   client.send_message('user3', 'Test')

Comment: As a side note, `event.message.to_dict()['from_id']` is *incredibly* wasteful. All you had to type is `event.from_id`.

Comment: Thanks. Will use it. Any idea how to solve my issue?

Comment: This issue has been solved plenty of times before on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=coroutine+was+never+awaited

Comment: I tried to add client.send_message('user3', 'Test') into async def normal_handler(event):, but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with the next code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events

#Ids
api_id = 99999
api_hash = 'secret_word'

client = TelegramClient('secret_chat', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=('user1')))
async def normal_handler(event):
    s_user_id=event.message.to_dict()['from_id']

    await client.send_message('user3', 'Test')

    if s_user_id != 99999999:
        client.send_message('user3', 'Test')



@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=('user2')))
async def normal_handler(event):

    s_user_id=event.message.to_dict()['from_id']

    await client.send_message('user3', 'Test')

    if s_user_id != 99999999:
        client.send_message('user3', 'Test')

client.start()

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

But now, client.send_message work even s_user_id = 99999999. 
Somehow the code is ignoring if s_user_id != 99999999:

Comment: You have a correct `send_message` call out of any conditionals, which always works. The `send_message` inside the conditional is missing `await` which won't work.

Comment: So, if i put await client.send_message('user3', 'Test') into if it will work?